# Como aplicar filtros nas consultas ao banco de dados em todas as requisições

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jpa

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando Spring Boot e Spring Data JPA que irá funcionar de maneira semelhante a um blog.

Nessa aplicação existem três tipos diferentes de usuário e cada usuário irá pertencer a diferentes grupos. Preciso fazer com que o usuário veja apenas os dados correspondentes a ele ou a um grupo do qual ele faz parte.

Existe alguma maneira de implementar filtros no Spring Boot que atuem em toda requisição e apliquem esses filtros na consulta ao banco de dados?

Por exemplo, o usuário do grupo 5 tentou ver os posts pertencentes aquele grupo, automaticamente é aplicado um filtro que retorne os posts direcionados para aquele grupo.

Grato pela ajuda!

Comment: Isso é bem difícil de definir baseado apenas na sua pergunta, provavelmente implementar um filtro ou interceptor do Spring para isso é um tiro no pé e lhe digo algumas causas: 1) Você teria de padronizar a forma de realizar queries (utilizando apenas Criteria por exemplo) para o filtro tratar sempre da mesma forma 2) A primeira definição trás problemas de portabilidade de soluções 3) Filtros vão atuar para todas as requisições, então não é possível filtrar todos os dados utilizando um admin, você terá que implementar essas exceções no filtro

Comment: Sugiro utilizar uma tática baseada em repositórios e entidades (como o [@Filter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-filter) do JPA), porém utilizando [JpaSpecificationExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html), dessa forma para a entidade você pode prover uma `Specification` incluindo a condição que você deseja sempre

Comment: Mauricio, não sei se no teu projeto vai existir autenticação. Se sim, uma implementação base tu pode encontrar aqui para essa parte de segurança, https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration. Depois disso, um sugestão é tu criar um Criteria mesmo (como nullptr comentou) com os dados/grupo do usuário que fez a requisição.